# How to save card details in stripe (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, stripe-payments

As you see my question i am confused because i saw many article and stripe documentation solutions for saving card every time i get something different. My application flow is something like that first user come and he will be given 2 options

1. previous saved cards
2. enter new card

#### Enter New card

In doing this i take card details from customer and then i am generating token and sending that token and  customerId that will be fetched from db(if old customer) and it means that customer is already generated and at backend i create customer first(if no customerId found) using the stripe token i get after adding payment information and then use the customerId i will charge the customer

```
stripe.charges.create({
        amount:amount,
        description: '',
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customerid
      })
```

#### Now here my question starts

I cannot use the token i got after adding payment details because that token is only for one time and I cannot use customerId directly to charge the customer then how I can charge the customer in future and how can i get a list of customers saved payment methods and delete or update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a token from Stripe, that token should then be used in a subsequent call to create a customer with that token. You can do so using the `stripe.customers.create` call. This will then convert that token into a source you can repeatedly use. See: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-source

When you retrieve that customer the next time around, you'll notice that the source persists in the customer object. See: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve

When creating another charge, use that new source_id found within the customer object instead of the source parameter. If you do not provide one, it'll use the default one set for that customer.

If you need to add additional cards to a customer, use the Card Creation API. This will allow you to create, update, and delete cards for a customer. See: https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create

Comment: so this means that when i get the token after adding payments and use that token and create the customer together with it,it will become the default payment method and next time when i again add new card then it will update customer and add new default payment method and if i retrive the customer object i will get the default payment method
i didn't understand how i can use it to charge the customer next time.

Comment: for example:-
stripe.charges.create(
  {
    amount: 2000,
    currency: 'usd',
    source: 'tok_amex', // <= can i add that id here
    description: 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs)',
  },  

am i right?

Comment: and for multiple cards:-
i can attatched many cards as i want, to the customer
stripe.customers.createSource(
  'cus_HdR5ZtGkkuZW5q', // customer id
  {source: 'tok_amex'}, // the token
  function(err, card) {
    // asynchronously called
  }

Comment: one more thing that is 
> i will also get these cards when i retrieve the customer, am i right?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Always create a customer or a card before charging. This way you can continuously use that token to charge. Take note that updating a customer will remove the previous card so use the Card API instead.

Answer (score 3):

First, when your customer adds a card on frontend, you can save it as a payment method and use it for later.

Frontend:

```js
const result = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: 'card',
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
        // Some details of your customer like email, name, etc
    },
});
```

And you have to send the `result.paymentMethod.id` to backend and create stripe customer with that `paymentMethod`.

```js
stripe.customers.create({
    email: emailAddress,
    invoice_settings: {
        default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
    },
    payment_method: paymentMethodId,
});
// paymentMethodId is the payment method id passed from frontend
```

You can check the below documents:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Note: You can only save the id of customer in your database and stripe will handle all of the others. You don't have to try to save something in your database for later usage.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe support few options for storing card details. You can store paymentMethod after initial payment or store card details and then pay.

**To store card details before payment:**

1. Crete StripeCustomer

```js
CustomerCreateParams params = CustomerCreateParams.builder()
            .setName("Customer name")
            .setEmail("customer@email")
            .build();
Customer customer = Customer.create(params);
```

2. Prepare SetupIntent object on backend

```js
SetupIntentCreateParams setupIntentCreateParams = SetupIntentCreateParams.builder().setCustomer(customer.getId()).build();
SetupIntent intent = SetupIntent.create(setupIntentCreateParams);
return new PrepareSetupResponse(intent.getClientSecret());
```

3. Send `intent.getClientSecret()` as `prepareSetupResponse.data.clientSecret` to frontend
4. Send `stripe.confirmCardSetup` and use `result.setupIntent.payment_method` to create `PaymentIntent` on backend

   `.setOffSession(true).setConfirm(true);` is important for offline payments

```js
Builder paramsBuilder = builder()
            .setCurrency("USD")
            .addPaymentMethodType("card")
            .setOffSession(true)
            .setConfirm(true);
            .setPaymentMethod(confirmSubscriptionRequest.getPaymentMethod())
            .setCustomer(customer.getId());
            
PaymentIntent intent = PaymentIntent.create(paymentIntentParameters.build());
```

Complete JS side example

```js
axios.post(prepareSetupUrl).then(prepareSetupResponse => {
      if (prepareSetupResponse.status === 200) {
        const clientSecret = prepareSetupResponse.data.clientSecret;
        stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret, {
          payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
            billing_details: {
              name: "cardholder name"
            }
          }
        }).then(result => {
          if (result.setupIntent && result.setupIntent.payment_method) {
            axios.post(preparePaymentUrl, {
              paymentMethod: result.setupIntent.payment_method
            }).then((confirmPaymentResponse) => {
              if (confirmPaymentResponse.status === 200) {
                this.props.history.push("/checkout/success");
              } else {
                this.props.history.push("/checkout/failed");
                console.log(confirmPaymentResponse.statusText);
              }
            }).catch(exception => {
              console.log(exception);
              this.props.history.push("/checkout/failed");
            });
          } else {
            that.props.history.push("/checkout/failed");
          }
        });
      }
```